# yum update failed

Tags: centos, yum, openvz, update

I have problem doing a yum update on my OpenVZ VPS.  I get this error message:

```
(56/69): glibc-devel-2.5-81.el5_8.7.x86_64.rpm           | 2.4 MB     00:00
(57/69): libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64.rpm     | 2.8 MB     00:00
(58/69): binutils-2.17.50.0.6-20.el5_8.3.x86_64.rpm      | 2.9 MB     00:00
(59/69): cpp-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64.rpm                 | 2.9 MB     00:00
(60/69): device-mapper-multipath-0.4.7-48.el5_8.1.x86_64 | 3.0 MB     00:00
(61/69): mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64.rpm                 | 3.5 MB     00:03
(62/69): coreutils-5.97-34.el5_8.1.x86_64.rpm            | 3.6 MB     00:00
(63/69): gcc-c++-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64.rpm             | 3.8 MB     00:00
(64/69): glibc-2.5-81.el5_8.7.x86_64.rpm                 | 4.8 MB     00:01
(65/69): gcc-4.1.2-52.el5_8.1.x86_64.rpm                 | 5.3 MB     00:01
(66/69): glibc-2.5-81.el5_8.7.i686.rpm                   | 5.4 MB     00:01
(67/69): python-libs-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.x86_64.rpm         | 5.9 MB     00:01
(68/69): mysql-server-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64.rpm          |  13 MB     00:07
(69/69): glibc-common-2.5-81.el5_8.7.x86_64.rpm          |  16 MB     00:03
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           2.4 MB/s | 106 MB     00:44
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqlaccess from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.77-4.el5_6.6.i386
  file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysql_find_rows from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/bin/mysqlaccess from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/my_print_defaults.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_find_rows.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysql_waitpid.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqladmin.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqldump.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/man/man1/mysqlshow.1.gz from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-5.1.58-

jason.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't have EPEL or some other repositories installed on here would you? If so, it's behaving like it's trying to update MySQL with the MySQL install in one of your other repositories rather than the one in the CentOS repos. Also before you do anything else, backup your MySQL databases with:

```
mysqldump -u <ROOT_USER> -p <DATABASE_NAME> > ~/<DATABASE_NAME>.sql
```

...for each of your databases. Because there are other repos involved, you can never be sure if they'll wipe out your my.cnf or your mysql data directory. Better be safe!

Disable your other repos temporarily and then perform the update.

Check in

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/
```

CentOS has version specific repos and it's important you have your installation set up for the correct repos otherwise you'll get more of these conflicts. This particular problem could be a result of:

```
protect=1
```

...being set next to a third-party repo or your primary repos having

```
protect=0
```

...so the software they update isn't protected from being updated by third-party repos.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You somehow installed the 32-bit version of MySQL and it conflicts with the third-party 64-bit version you are trying to install.

To fix the problem, remove the existing 32-bit MySQL installation before installing the new packages. For instance:

```
yum remove mysql*.i386
```

Comment: In my case we were trying to update 64 bit version of mysql but this was being prevented by the existence of an unknown to us 32bit version, once removed as described above the 64bit yum update went through just dandy.

Comment: also add exclude=*.i?86 *.i686 to your yum.conf